# "is" operator not working correctly for float values

Tags: python, arrays

I'm writing a function that takes in an array and removes all the zeros (including `0.0`) in the array and returns the modified array.

```
def remove_zeros(array):
    array = [i for i in array if not(i is 0 or i is 0.0)]
    return array
```

Sample input:

```
array = [1, 0.0, 0, False, None, 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[1, False, None, 1, 2]
```

I'm using the `is` operator because when I use `==` it also removes `False` as `False` logically evaluates to `0`.
However the `is` operator does not work for `float`s for some reason. Instead of the correct output I'm getting:

```
[1, 0.0, False, None, 1, 2]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should not use `is` for numerical comparisons; it checks for object identity which is not the same thing. Just use `==` and (and consider perhaps `is not False` and `is not None` if you want to skip those values).

Comment: Also, you rarely want to test floating-point values for equality. For example, `1/3 != 0.333333333333`, but depending on the application, they are probably close enough.

Comment: @larsks thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the “is” operator checks if `id(var1) == id(var2)` (id is like the address of the var in the memory). If the id of two vars equals, that means they’re the same instance.

Because python caches all the integers between -5 and 256 (because they’re used very frequently), if you compare the id of two equal integers in that range, they’ll be the same.

But floats aren’t cached, so you can’t compare any of them using the “is” operator.

You shouldn’t use the “is” operator unless you want to check if two vars points to the same instance (i.e. `if x is None`).

To solve the problem, you can add a check that the value is not false:

```py
array = [i for i in array if i != 0 or i is False]
```

Because True and False are singletons, you can check if a var is really False or True (and not just evaluates to one of them) using the “is” operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to remove numeric values that evaluate to zero, you could make your code more explicit:

```
def remove_zeros(array):
    return [i for i in array if i != 0 or not isinstance(i, (int, float))]
```

`is` works for floats, for example try evaluating `0.0 is 0.0`. But you don't want to be using it here as `is` is asking about object identity, not value and your `i` *is* not `0.0` - they are referring to different entities.

Comment: `is` *might* work. `float` values are not interned like small `int` values are in CPython.